# jQuery-File-Upload (blueimp) - how do I access the error value both in JS end and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file, upload

How do I test if the file uploaded has returned an error using blueimps file uploader.

The uploader only allows a single file upload (must be an image).

I have the following js code

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    singleFileUploads: true ,
    submit: function (e, data) {
       $('#upload_overlay').fadeIn(300);
    },
    done: function (e, data) {



      if(typeof data.files.error == "undefined"){
        $('#err_succ_msg').html('Photo successfully updated.').css('background-color','#B1DD8B').show(1);
        $('#upload_overlay').fadeOut(300);
      }
      else{

        $('#err_succ_msg').html('Photo update failed. Please try again.').css('background-color','#F76151').show(1);
        $('#upload_overlay').fadeOut(300);
      }

    },

    fail: function (e, data) {
      $('#err_succ_msg').html('Photo update failed. Please try again.').css('background-color','#F76151').show(1);
      $('#upload_overlay').fadeOut(300);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

In the "done" function I'm trying to find out if there is a error so I can show the correct message to the user.

I've tried "alerting" out data.result[0].error and data.files[data.index].error but it either comes out blank or has a "data.result[0]" is undefined.

Mostly from this question here: [blueImp/jquery file upload - How do I get the error message if the file type was not accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506459/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-how-do-i-get-the-error-message-if-the-file-type-was)

also on the PHP side of things how do I check if there is an error. For example the PHP index file has this:

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

What do I need to figure out if there is an error so I do some processing on the server side?

Comment: apologies for the poor formatting - for the life of me I cant figure out how I make the code look pretty with the syntax heighlighting.

Comment: @chresse - thanks for the re-formatting!

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up on this. This is how I accessed the object data on the JS side:

`data['jqXHR']['responseJSON']['files'][0]['error']`

so getting the name of the file for example would be

`data['jqXHR']['responseJSON']['files'][0]['name']`

On the PHP side in the end I just put my code in the function "body" in the file uploadHandler.php

I had to convert the JSON formatted string into an array to access the data

`protected function body($str) {
        $new_array = json_decode($str, true);`

....

So I could access this like this

`$new_array['files'][0]['name']`

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: thanks @KB but  responseJSON inside the jqXHR only returns the JSON array returned by the server right ?? So, if my backend code don't return filenames on success does it mean that I will be unable to display the files uploaded ??